# How can I line up 3"cards" using the inline-block function in css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have 3 cards (HTML) line up in a row using CSS, I think I am not pointing the css (display: inline-block )rule to the right element in HTML. I have have tried to do a trial and error on all tags associated with the cards but nothing is happening.

I want it to look like this:
[image]

The code is below and his is how I tried to add the CSS (display inline-block rule) - I am using Visual Studio to write the code.

1. main {display: inline-block;}  **Nothing happens when I use this code in css**
2. section {display: inline-block;} **Nothing happens when I use this code in css**
3. div {display: inline-block;} **Nothing happens when I use this code in css**
4. .card {display: inline-block;} **Nothing happens when I use this code in css**
5. .card {{display: flex;} **Nothing happens when I use this code in css**
6. I have tried wrapping the cards in a div tag and applying display flex - Nothing happens
   `

```
Here is the code:
`
`<main>
   <section class="card">
       <div id="row1">
            <img src="images/card1.jpg" alt="Nova Scotia" />
            <div>
         
                <h3>Explore Nova Scotia</h3>
                <p class="description">On board a small sailing ship leaving Lunenburg.</p>
                <p class="social"><span class="heart">112</span><span class="comment">23</span></p>
            </div>
      </div>
   </section>


   <section class="card">

         <div id="row2">
           <img src="images/card2.jpg" alt="Santorini" />
              <div>
         
                <h3>Dusk on Santorini</h3>
                <p class="description">Devoted yourself to the sunset!.</p>
                <p class="social"><span class="heart">2313</span><span class="comment">18</span></p>
              </div>
        </div>
   
  </section>   

   <section class="card">

      <div id="row3">
      <img src="images/card3.jpg" alt="Chicago" />
      <div>
         
         <h3>Amsterdam Flower Market</h3>
         <p class="description">The only floating flower market in the world.</p>
         <p class="social"><span class="heart">14</span><span class="comment">5</span></p>
      </div>
   </div>
  *your text*

   </section>   
</main>``
```

Comment: The `<div id="row2">` are unnecessary. That ID would make sense in `<section>`  or nowhere at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `display: flex;` on the cards common parent.
- Assign a class to it like `.cards`
- Get rid of the unnecessary `id=""`

```css
.cards {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.card {
  flex: 1;
}

.card img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10rem;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="cards">
    <section class="card">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/150" alt="Nova Scotia" />
      <div>
        <h3>Explore Nova Scotia</h3>
        <p class="description">On board a small sailing ship leaving Lunenburg.</p>
        <p class="social"><span class="heart">112</span><span class="comment">23</span></p>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="card">
      <div id="row2">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/300" alt="Santorini" />
        <div>
          <h3>Dusk on Santorini</h3>
          <p class="description">Devoted yourself to the sunset!.</p>
          <p class="social"><span class="heart">2313</span><span class="comment">18</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section class="card">
      <div id="row3">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" alt="Chicago" />
        <div>
          <h3>Amsterdam Flower Market</h3>
          <p class="description">The only floating flower market in the world.</p>
          <p class="social"><span class="heart">14</span><span class="comment">5</span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
  
  <!-- other <main> stuff here -->
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help , I'm a newbie at HTML & CSS. Appreciate the assistance.

Comment: @FadzaiEmmahNembaware you're very welcome. Happy coding